# Simple Boolean 'isSet'

Tags: java, boolean, assertion

So I have two sets of code, one for Employer, one for Employee, I have been given a UML diagram telling me what exactly to make, but I'm having problems with one specific part...

The Employee has two main variables, an ID and Name..

On the UML, it says

> Returns true if the name and id have been set to the non-default values. False otherwise.'

This is my current code:

```
public boolean isSet() {
    if (!(name.equals("NOT SET") && id == -1)) {
        return true;
    } else {
    return false;
    }
}
```

Provided was a JUnit test to go against, I've been ripping my hair out for hours now...

```
public void testIsSet() {
    Employee e = new Employee("Mr Tumble");
    e.setId(99);
    assertTrue(e.isSet());
    e.setId(-1);
    assertFalse(e.isSet());
    e.setId(0);
    assertTrue(e.isSet());
    e.setName("NOT_SET");
    assertFalse(e.isSet());   
}
```

Above is what it tests against, it fails on the setId(-1) part, which is the default value that the ID is set to before it is assigned by making a new Employee.

Is my code wrong? I feel like its something really small but I just cant see it!

Thanks in advance, 
Any input is much appreciated!

Comment: You've returning `true` now if name is set OR id is not -1. Switch `&&` to `||`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return true if "the name AND id" have been set. Your if statement will return true if either the name OR the id has been set. Try this:

```
public boolean isSet() {
    if (!name.equals("NOT SET") && id != -1)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```